# DataSourceRequest fields are not populated with post triggered by Kendo UI grid when calling MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, kendo-ui, null, grid

I’m smashing my head for few days already trying to get grid server site filtering working for my Angular 6 and Kendo UI. When I set filter on the UI I can see data in posted body of the message  like “filter=Item~contains~'SL-'&page=1&pageSize=5” however this information is not mapped correctly on the MVC controller site to DataSourceRequest object 
This is my Angular service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import {
    toDataSourceRequestString,
    translateDataSourceResultGroups,
    translateAggregateResults,
    DataResult,
    DataSourceRequestState
} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { GridDataResult, DataStateChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { sampleProducts } from '../delivery-manager/products'
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeliveryDataSvrService {
    private BASE_URL: string = 'GetDeliveryDetailsForGrid';
    //private BASE_URL: string = 'DeliveryManager/GetDeliveryDetailsForGrid';
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    }

    public fetch(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {



        return this.http
            .post<DataResult>(this.BASE_URL, toDataSourceRequestString(state)) 
            .map((data: any) =>
                (<GridDataResult>{
                    data: data.Data,
                    total: data.Total,
                })
            )

    }
}
```

This is my MVC controller

```
using DataAccess;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace KingspanAUGears.Controllers
{
    public class DeliveryManagerController : Controller

        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetDeliveryDetailsForGrid( [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            // request is null for PageSize, Filters, Sorts 


            var ctx = new KingspanAUToolsEntities();
            var toReturn = ctx.TruckDriversJobDetails.Take(100).ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(toReturn);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DataQuery toDataSourceRequestString](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/toDataSourceRequestString/) function creates a query string that will be properly parsed by the DataSourceRequest model binder in the Controller, and is supposed to be used with a GET request:

[Documentation article and example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/mvc-integration/)

If needed, perhaps you can tweak the Angular data service as follows to send the state in a POST request:

```
public fetch(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<any> {
    const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; //serialize the state
    const hasGroups = state.group && state.group.length;

    const obj = toDataSourceRequest(state);
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
    };

    return this.http
        .post(`${this.BASE_URL}`, queryStr, httpOptions) //send the state to the server         
        .map((res:any) => // process the response
            (<GridDataResult>{
                //if there are groups convert them to compatible format
                data: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(res.Data) : res.Data,
                total: res.Total,
                // convert the aggregates if such exists
                //aggregateResult: translateAggregateResults(aggregateResults)
            })
        )
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostProducts([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {

        var result = Json(this.products.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        return result;
    }

    private IEnumerable products = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name = "Smith" },
        new { ID = 2, Name = "John" }
    };
```

Comment: There is no problem with sending all the data to server, all information gets there in request both for Post in the body and Get in the header. However filters are not get mapped correctly in DataSourceRequest object, they are still null. On the other hand page and pagesize are getting through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the suggested adjustments? Here is a screenshot of the request received on my end when I type "s" in the Name column Grid filter:

[image]

The Content-Type in the HttpHeaders needs to be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and the filters get mapped as expected:

Comment: I implemented all the changes you proposed and I’m very jealous just because I can see that it works for you. However in my case the same request object for Filters always shows null, hopeless case.

Comment: I put together a sample project so you can inspect it and compare what other adjustments might be required in your scenario:

https://github.com/dtopalov/net-core-angular-kendo-post

Comment: Thanks for that, you solution is based on .net core. I use full .net4.6 so I will not be able to fully compare those projects